# How to pull down coordinator layout when there is no scrolling content

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout

I am loading three fragments using tab layout and view pager. I am hiding top bar when user scrolling down the page. For instance fragment A has not less data, whereas fragment B and fragment C has more data and on scrolling down and up is hiding and showing back the top bar.

My problem is when I go to fragment B or fragment C and scroll down, top bar is hidden and then go back to fragment A, the top bar remains hidden.  I want to show the top bar when there is no scrolling content. What is the correct way to pull down the top bar when any fragment has no scrolling content.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".DetailActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/search_back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_medium"
            android:text="James"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_color_one"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/borrower_overview_background">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:background="@color/content_background"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tabIconTint="@color/colaba_red_color"
            app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/app_blue"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/app_blue"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/grey_color_two" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colaba_app_border_color"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detail_tab_layout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/detailViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/content_background_color" />

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It May Work i THINK LIKE you can use the viewmodel for this by changing the layout themes dynamically
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture